Why is there omitted variable bias in my regression of uncorrelated regressors?
I am running a LASSO regression on Bernoulli uncorrelated variables, i.e. each variable has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of having value 0 or 1. My undertanding is that there should be no ommitted variable bias in this setting. However, it appears that when I omit some of the variables, one of the remaining regressors consistently gets larger with the other variables omitted. This regressor happens to be the one that has the largest coefficient by far.
Could someone help me understand why there would be ommitted variable bias in this setting? The only other reason I can think of that would invalidate the model is the assumption that the residuals are uncorrelated with the regressors. Is this perhaps the reason the largest coeffient consistenly gets larger when other variables are ommitted?
Or is the reason more likely to do with the LASSO regularization? My understanding is that LASSO shrinks small coefficients to 0, but can "compensate" by making the large coefficients even larger. Would this then apply to ommitted variable bias as well? I.e., in a lasso regression, if we delete some regressors that had large coefficients, will the regularization cause some of the remaining coefficients to become proportionally larger?
EDIT:
I tried running the regression without LASSO regularization, and I still see the bias in that leading coefficient when some of the variables are ommitted. So I think it must be coming from correlation with the residual?
EDIT2:
The exact specification of my problem is as follows:
$y^t \sim \sum_{i=1}^{10000} x^t_i\beta_i + \beta_0$
My design matrix is $(26,000 \times 10,000)$, i.e. low number of observations per feature, but still significantly more than the number of features. Each regression variable is bermoulli distributed as  $x_i \sim \mathbf{B}(\frac{1}{2})$.
To understand the dependent variable, it will help to understand the problem better. I am studing the theory of datamodeling, as described in this paper by Ilyas et. al. (2022). In that paper, they look at how different subsets of some training set affect the output of the model on a specific input. This involves re-building the model many thousands of times (26 thousand in my case) on different random subsets of the training data (which for me was the CIFAR-10 test set). The observations then consist of boolean vectors representing the mask used for training. Since the training superset has 10000 points total, the number of points included in each model's training data naturally concentrates at around 5000 points, though it has some variation around the mean of course). The goal of the regression is then to be able to predict the output of the model based on which training points were included. In my case, I'm trying to predict the correct-class margin of the model, which tends to be in the range $(-10,10)$ or threreabouts. Since each regressor takes on values in 0/1, each coefficient can be thought of as the net contribution of each training point to the final model's correct class margin.
With that in mind, the question I asked amounts to: when I remove ~500 points from the training superset, so that each individual model is now trained on some random subset of ~4750 training points, how does this impact the regression coefficients?
EDIT3:
Below is the code where I ran the OLS regression with some comments. Hopefully this suffices to show what I mean. Each row of the original mask1 martix (25580x10000) was created using mask1 = (np.random.rand(10_000) > 0.5). masks2 was created the same way, but then 500 of the columns were deleted, removing them from the regression.
#run regular regression

S=2
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
#both masks were generated using i.i.d. bernoulli variables
print("number of all-zero columns originally: "+str(len(np.where(np.max(masks1,axis=0)>0)[0]))
print("number of all-zero columns with mask over 500 variables: "+str(len(np.where(np.max(masks2,axis=0)>0)[0]))
reg_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg_model1 = LinearRegression().fit(masks1, confidences1[:,nextLayerInds[S]])
reg_model2 = LinearRegression().fit(masks2, confidences2[:,nextLayerInds[S]])
coefs1 = reg_model1.coef_
coefs2 = reg_model2.coef_
diagCoef1 = coefs1[nextLayerInds[S]]
diagCoef2 = coefs2[nextLayerInds[S]]
print("diagCoefs1: " + str(diagCoef1)+", diagCoefs2: " + str(diagCoef2))
#this coefficient is the largest one, it in particular increases the most.

number of all-zero columns originally: 10000
number of all-zero columns with mask over 500 variables: 9500
mask shape: (25580, 10000)
coefs1 shape: (10000,), coefs2 shape: (10000,)
diagCoefs1: 0.9914176741046912, diagCoefs2: 1.1515776668486513

EDIT 4:
I finally went and checked all of the correlations. They seem to range from -.06 to .06. I was actually surprised they were that high in magnitude... when I simply generate a (17000x10000) random bernoulli matrix, the max correlation is more like .03. I'm not sure why the discrepancy, so I'm making all of my data again. But even with an absolute maximum of .06 correlation over 10000 regressors, I don't think it would explain a change in one particular coefficients of 30%, which is what I'm seeing.
Paul

The well known consequences of omitted variable bias apply to OLS estimation. I think LASSO estimation may be different. It is weird you are getting the effect even with OLS. Could you share a simulation illustrating the behavior you are seeing? Also, the phrasing of your first sentence reminds me more of autocorrelation that correlation across regressors. Are you sure your regressors are uncorrelated between themselves (not necessarily within)?

Please include in your post your LASSO regression equation and the description of each variable involved

Providing a reproducible example would help here. Putting aside the LASSO issue, is this least-squares regression or is it perhaps a logistic regression?

Thank you @RichardHardy for your comment -- I will get back with a simulation today. To answer your other question, yes I am sure they are uncorrelated amongst themselves. The actual regression I'm running is from this codebase: https://github.com/MadryLab/datamodels. They are essentially modeling how the confidence of the model relates to the inclusion/exclusion of different training data. Each feature is a 0/1 for inclusion of each training point, which occurrs with i.i.d. probability 1/2 for each point.

@AlecosPapadopoulos how do I upload the data I'm using for the regression so you can try it yourself? Given my edit, I think it would be sufficient to understand why this is happening even with OLS.

@Paul You describe your "explanatory variables" are Bernoulli's each having $p=0.5$. What is your dependent variable? Is is continuous, discrete? What is its actual range in the sample? Also, does your regression equation includes a constant term? ...All these questions would have been answered immediately if you have included in the post your specification as suggested

I just added the specification of my model as a second edit, and some description of the actual problem. I can add my data as soon as I figure out a way to do so and share here.

It would be helpful if you could give a sub-sample of your data so people can reproduce your scenario. Something akin to dput() in R. It also remains unclear whether your question is specifically about the LASSO case or a general statement on uncorrelated regressors.

I don't use Python much, but I vaguely recall that in its linear regression functions you have to include a constant/intercept column of 1s explicitly in your model matrix if you want to fit the $\beta_0$ term in the description of your model. The formula given for mask1 doesn't seem to include a constant column. Was that in fact included?

@Kuku ok sure thing, I could share maybe 100 columns and 500 observations -- maybe it will still show the effect. where do I put that?

I am not familiar with the code you posted. Where in this code is the existence of a constant term in the OLS regression you run? I am asking because this is a critical issue.

I edited my code snippet a few of days ago to include the import statement for the python package I'm using for linear regression. Its from scikit learn :https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html. Looks like it does use an intercept by dedault. Though I do really appreciate your proof about the intercept, and I think it could potentially be relevant. So It seems we can rule out the intercept, correlations, or LASSO regularization as being the cuplrit. What is left? Endogeneity?

We show for the case of two regressors, that in the setup of the OP (two i.i.d Bernoullis as regressors, large sample), if the regression specification does not include a constant term, then the coefficient estimate for the remaining one goes up, if we drop the other.
Note that we do not postulate some "true" data generating mechanism: we only use the algebraic expressions for the OLS estimator.
We first implement the estimating equation
$$y_i = \beta_1x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i}, \qquad i =1\dots n.$$
The OLS estimator is
$$\left[\begin{matrix}  \hat \beta_1 \\ \hat \beta_2 \end{matrix} \right] = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
Writing
$$S^2_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ji}^2, \; j=1,2, \qquad S_{12} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}x_{2i},\quad S_{yj} = \sum_{i=1}^n =y_ix_{ji}, \; j=1,2$$
We have
$$(X'X)^{-1}X'y = (S^2_1S^2_2 -S^2_{12})^{-1} \cdot  \left[\begin{matrix} S^2_2 & -S_{12} \\ -S_{12} & S^2_1 \end{matrix} \right] \cdot \left[\begin{matrix} S_{y1} \\ S_{y2} \end{matrix}\right]$$
From this we get the estimate for $\hat \beta_1$ as
$$\hat \beta_1 = \frac{S^2_2\cdot S_{y1} -S_{12}S_{y2} }{S^2_1S^2_2 -S^2_{12}} \tag {1}$$
In our case the regressors are $0/1$ and so the sum of squares is equal to the sum of levels which is equal to the number of times they are realized as equal to $1$.
Denote $m_1$ the number of $x_1 =1$, $m_2$ the number of $x_2 =1$  and $m_{12}$ the number of observations at which both are equal to unity. Then we can re-write eq. $(1)$ as
$$\hat \beta_1 = \frac{m_2\cdot S_{y1} -m_{12}S_{y2} }{m_1m_2 -m^2_{12}} \tag {2}$$
Suppose now that we drop the second regressor and our estimating equation becomes
$$y = \gamma_1 x_1$$
Then
$$\hat \gamma_1 = \frac{S_{y1}}{S^2_1} = \frac{S_{y1}}{m_1} \tag{3}$$
We want to show that
\begin{align}
\hat \gamma_1 > \hat \beta_1 \; & \implies \; \frac{S_{y1}}{m_1} > \frac{m_2\cdot S_{y1} -m_{12}S_{y2} }{m_1m_2 -m^2_{12}} \\
&\\
& \implies S_{y1}\cdot (m_1m_2 -m^2_{12}) > m_1m_2S_{y1} - m_1m_{12}S_{y2}\\
&\\
&\implies m_1S_{y2} > m_{12}S_{y1}\\
&\\
&\implies \frac{m_2}{m_{12}}\frac {1}{m_2}S_{y2} > \frac{1}{m_1}S_{y1} \tag{4}\\
\end{align}
Because both regressors are Bernoulis with the same $p$, we expect, especially for large sample sizes as the OP uses, that
$$\frac {1}{m_2}S_{y2} \approx \frac{1}{m_1}S_{y1}$$
Moreover, fundamentally
$$m_2 > m_{12}$$
because $m_2$ is linked to a marginal probability and $m_{12}$ is linked to a joint probability. In fact, since the two Bernoullis are independent
$$\frac {m_2} {n} \approx \Pr(x_2=1)> \Pr(x_1=1) \cdot\Pr(x_2=1) = \Pr(x_1=1, x_2=1) \approx   \frac {m_{12}} {n}.$$
Hence $m_2 / m_{12} > 1$ and the left-hand side of $(4)$ is almost certain to be larger in value than the right-hand side, and we have shown what we wanted to show.

thank you very much for your answer. However, based on the documentation for the LienarRegression package I linked in my comment above, there is in fact an intercept in the regression. So I don't think this is the explanation.

Omitted variable bias refers to variables that are unmeasured and unmodeled.  What you have is instead known as suppressor effects.  The inclusion or exclusion of certain variables substantially changes the coefficients for others that remain in your model.  This condition is not specific to LASSO implementation.
This situation can only occur when there are nonzero correlations between predictors; when resulting levels of tolerance for one or more predictors fall well below 1; and when the variance inflation factor for such predictors falls well above 1.

Hello, thank you for your reply. In my case, all of the predictors are uncorrelated.

I'm thinking you intended them to be uncorrelated but they are correlated in actuality.  Have you obtained r's?

@Paul all predictors arise from a DGP that will converge to uncorrelatedness. However, if I understand correctly, you are not orthogonalizing the predictors before they enter the model, so that almost surely their sample correlation is nonzero. That's all it takes for inclusion/exclusion of covariates to change values (not sure I'd call that OVB though).

@Kuku With 25 thousand observations, is very unlikely that any "artificial" sample correlation between regressors will survive, if they are drawn as i.i.d.

@AlecosPapadopoulos You are right

yes, I don't believe there are really nonzero correlations given the dimensions of the data matrix

@AlecosPapadopoulos it does seem like the maximum of the 10000*9999 off-diagonal correlations is actually as high as .06-ish. but most are between -.02 and .02
